# Create a trigger which will increment the comm by amount 100 whenever salary is getting incremented

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table emp which contains empno,ename,sal,comm and some other fields.I want to fire a trigger such when user updates the salary the comm field will get increased by 100. I have written following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trr40  
AFTER UPDATE of sal   
ON emp 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN    
  if :new.sal>:old.sal then 
    update emp set comm=comm+10;
  end if;
END;`
```

I am getting an error which says system.emp table is mutating!!
please help!!

Comment: Sorry, I post to mysql. it is mysql or oracle?

Comment: Ok. I will remove my response. Please, add the tag oracle, because oracle's user will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't issue it as a separate update statement to avoid this error as you can't have two updates happening at the same time to the same row. Instead, set the value directly within this transaction, and make the trigger test BEFORE the update instead of AFTER.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trr40  
BEFORE update of sal   
ON emp for each row 
BEGIN    
 if :new.sal>:old.sal 
 then 
   :new.comm := :old.comm+10;
  end if;
END;
```

Comment: error says cannot change new values for this trigger

Comment: Actually I see that the update is to another table. My bad. Does that other table have a trigger that is updating back to SAL so that this trigger would cause an update to EMP which causes an update back to SAL?

Comment: we have sal and comm in same table

Comment: Create a trigger which will increment the comm by amount 100 whenever salary is getting incremented

Comment: I noticed that my assignment was wrong, "=" instead of ":=", and switched the RHS to :old.com+10.

Comment: Switch it to BEFORE UPDATE of SAL

Comment: AFTER UPDATE fires after the row changes have been written to disk, so additional data changes are not allowed. BEFORE UPDATE allows you to include business logic to update other values in the row. It is often used to do things like set audit column values, to check if the update should be allowed to proceed for business reasons, or for circumstances like yours.